# Benchmarking postgresql in hammerDB

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking, hammerdb

I'm trying to benchmark postgresql in hammerdb getting below error:

```
Vuser 1:Checkpoint and Vacuum
Error in Virtual User 1: ERROR:  must be superuser to do CHECKPOINT
Vuser 1:FINISHED FAILED
Vuser 13:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 18:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 8:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 5:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 21:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 9:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 16:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 20:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 6:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 14:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 19:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 11:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 15:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 17:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 7:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 3:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 10:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 12:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 2:FINISHED SUCCESS
Vuser 4:FINISHED SUCCESS
ALL VIRTUAL USERS COMPLETE
runtimer returned after 416 seconds
vudestroy success
TEST SEQUENCE COMPLETE
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue and which user to be mapped as super user.

Comment: Use a database user that has superuser permissions

Comment: how can I check which user has superuser permission or do I need to give postgres user with sudo permission

Comment: Check the results from SELECT * FROM pg_roles; The user "postgres" is usually superuser.

Comment: I'm able to fetch the details but unable to confirm if the user has superuser privilege's or not: Below is the output, can you please help to enable superuser permission:

Comment: rolname          | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit | rolpassword | rolvaliduntil | rolbypassrl
s | rolconfig |  oid  
---------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+---------------

 postgres                  | f        | t          | t             | t           | t           | f              |           -1 | ********    |               | f          
  |           | 16389

Comment: Second column, "rolsuper" says "t" from true.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable HammerDB from calling checkpoint and vacuum at the end of a test with the following command:

```
hammerdb>diset tpcc pg_vacuum false
Changed tpcc:pg_vacuum from true to false for PostgreSQL
```

If running long running or multiple tests on PostgreSQL it is recommended to enable Autovacuum to ensure that vacuuming is ongoing during tests to prevent bloat. When autovacuum is enabled it is not necessary to do so manually.